# How to make url and google bar into one UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

in the new safari on the mac they have a bar that can distinguish between google and a url.Thats what i am trying to do. I am wondering what i am doing wrong. It only wants to google not search url. Thanks in advance.

```
-(IBAction)SearchAll:(id)sender
{
    if (googlebar) {
        NSString *query = [googlebar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co./search?q=%@", query]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:request];

    }
    else{

        NSString *query = [googlebar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@", query]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:request];

    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting errors?

Comment: and how did you define searchBar? (in the beginning of your if statement)

Comment: IBOutlet UITextField *searchBar;  @Coder404

Comment: You can't say if (searchBar){}. a UITextfield wont return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is way off. You will not achieve your goal this way.

Secondly, You should start off your IBAction statement by checking if the string that was input into the search bar (or urlbar whatever you want to call it) has a prefix of .com or .org...etc. If it does not then it then google searches the text in the UITextfield.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure of your if statement?
you're using searchbar in the else, where searchbar if supposed not to exist.

you should also check the google.co./search url. I'd use google.com/search as it will save you a redirect

I'm still confused by your question though, as you have two toolbars: searchbar and googlebar, not one as in the latest safari for mac

Comment: It only wants to google not search url. Also what do you mean by google.com/search